# Como usar mercadopago con React JS

Tags: reactjs, mercadopago

hace ya mas de unas semanitas que estoy intentando poder cobrar con mercadopago en mi sitio web con react. Pero no puedo, intento y hago busquedas de todo tipo para solucionarlo pero veo muy poco.

Estoy utilizando el module:

> npm install mercadopago

Luego, como referencia tomo la guía de [MercadoPago Checkout Integration](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/payments/web-payment-checkout/integration/)

En mi sitio web, al estar en el ultimo paso, ejecuto esta funcion pasandole los valores que el usuario agrego (ya nose que mas intentar):

```
loadPago = (values) => {
    var mercadopago = require('mercadopago');
    var config = require('./MercadoPago/mercadopago.json');
    var accessToken = config.access_token;
    var clientID = config.client_id;
    var clientSC =  config.client_secret;
  
            // Agrega credenciales
            mercadopago.configure({
                sandbox:true,
            access_token: accessToken,
            client_id: clientID,
            client_secret: clientSC
            });
            
            let preference = {
                items: [
                  {
                    title: values.trabajos.nombre,
                    unit_price: values.trabajos.pesos,
                    quantity: 1,
                  }
                ]
              };


   // verifico que los datos se esten almacenando por asi decirlo
              console.log(preference); 

              mercadopago.preferences.create(preference)
              .then(function(response){
              // Este valor reemplazará el string "$$init_point$$" en tu HTML
                global.init_point = response.body.init_point;
              }).catch(function(error){
                console.log(error);
              });

  }
```

Le envio la funcion al componente:

```
        <FormPrecios 
            prevStep={this.prevStep}
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            loadPago={this.loadPago}
            values={values}
          />
```

Y en el component donde esta el boton:

```
 pagar = e => {
  const {values} = this.props;
   e.preventDefault();
  this.props.loadPago(values);
 }

 <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={this.pagar} className="mr-1 d-inline">
  Pagar
</Button>
```

De esta manera obtengo un error

> "Unknown Case", MercadoPagoError.
>
> SSL Error: https://mercadopago.com.ar/preferences?access_token=test1234123123(example)
> does not support SSL.
>
> Status 500

Despues intente una forma de cargar el script de mercadopago el cual genera el boton de Pagar, pero de esta manera obtenia el error de:

> [Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/'
> because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy
> directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' *.mercadolibre.com".

Investigue y segun lo que lei, react no se lleva bien con el tema de abrir links en una nueva ventana o modals/iframes, como algún error de seguridad o compatibilidad.

> Alguien sabe mi error? Donde tengo que mejorar o existe la posiblidad
> de usar mercadopago en react?

Comment: Aclaración: el sitio web posee SSL Certificate. por las dudas.

Comment: Por lo que menciona la documentación parece ser que la integración de checkout es para usarlo en una aplicación hecha con Node.js, no directamente en la app frontend (React).

Comment: Y cuales serían las mejores opciones de implementar mercadopago en react? Usando el script de JS? Haciendo backend y consumir API? Yo de igual manera estoy buscando poder cobrar con un simple formulario que los mande a mercadopago. No quiero cobrar en mi web/app pero no consigo la manera.

Comment: La opción "Crear Link de Pago" la exploraste? Es bastante simple y te permite crear un botón de pago, o generar uno automaticamente.

Comment: Te permite mandarle valores y que se genere automaticamente? o te referis al que creas manualmente en la web? Justamente ese quiero dejar de usar.

Comment: No, solamente se crea manualmente. Ahora me queda más claro lo que queres hacer.

Comment: Realizar una [experiencia de compra personalizada](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/payments/api/previous-requirements/) implica crear un token desde el frontend (react) y enviar el mismo a tu backend para que sea procesado. En ambos casos se utiliza las librerías oficiales de MercadoPago.

Comment: Osea que de igual manera, lo más practico seria que desde React (front) le mande las cosas al back y se procese desde ahi? Me conviene usar el modulo React Router para el tema del backend /procesar-pago ?

Comment: Y si tu aplicación tiene múltiple rutas como `/pago_existoso` y `/pago_en_proceso` React Router es necesario.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110506/discussion-between-juan-marco-and-juan).

Comment: empece una implementacion de MercadoPago en react, quisiera saber si pudiste resolver tu conflicto. y si es viable esta implementacion

Comment: La única solución posible que encontré investigando, es usar node o express js, para hacer un backend y mandarlo a react. Pero en si, desde React no se puede usar MercadoPago SDK.

Comment: @Juan quería saber si lo llegas a implementar de alguna manera, ya sea desde el back u otra forma; ahora estoy con esa misma duda.

Comment: @Shiranai por el momento lo deje en standby. Me dijieron que únicamente se puede usando back node Express y mandarlo al front de react. Si llego a hacer la implementación, subir un git :)